# Why is @EnableOAuth2Sso deprecated?

Tags: java, spring-security, oauth-2.0

Why is `@EnableOAuth2Sso` deprecated in Spring Security?
That's the only reason why OAuth2 will work for me.

If I remove `@EnableOAuth2Sso`, then this will not work

```
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Client
@EnableOAuth2Sso <- Need to have this!
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/Intranet/Bokning").authenticated()
        .antMatchers("/**", "/Intranet**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll();
    }

}
```

Is there another solution?

Comment: The [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-oauth2-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/client/EnableOAuth2Sso.html) linked to [this github page](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/wiki/OAuth-2.0-Migration-Guide), which is a migration guide. Seems like you need to do [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/wiki/OAuth-2.0-Migration-Guide#simplified-enablement-1)

Comment: This could be a useful link: https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/

Comment: Html = boring  :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a solution to latest Spring Security with Facebook OAuth2.0.

Security:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/Intranet/Bokning").authenticated() // Block this 
        .antMatchers("/**", "/Intranet**").permitAll() // Allow this for all
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll()
        .and()
        .oauth2Login();
    }
}
```

And `appllication.yml`

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
           facebook:
              clientId: myID
              clientSecret: mySecret
              accessTokenUri: https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token
              userAuthorizationUri: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth
              tokenName: oauth_token
              authenticationScheme: query
              clientAuthenticationScheme: form
              resource:
                 userInfoUri: https://graph.facebook.com/me

server:
  port: 8080
```

And `pom.xml` file:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: class WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is deprecated now.

Answer (score 4):

In Spring Security 5.2.x those annotations are deprecated and we need to use DSL method.

```
public class SecurityConf extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.oauth2Client(); //equivalent to @EnableOAuth2Client
    http.oauth2Login();  //equivalent to @EnableOAuth2Sso

}
```

Spring OAuth2 migration guide
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/wiki/OAuth-2.0-Migration-Guide